# jQuery.corner.js in IE8 being weird

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, internet-explorer-8, rounded-corners

I am using jQuery.corner.js to put a top-rounded background behind the titles of all blog posts at http://s3.mynewsitereview.com/category/ask-holly

It works perfectly in Firefox, Opera, Safari, Chrome, and IE9. In IE8, though, only the first post has the rounded corners. Any subsequent posts' titles do not have the rounded corners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID's must be unique. change your id's to classes and select using a class selector and things should start working.

Your code would change to:

```
$(function() { 
    $('.posthead').corner("top"); 
});
```

and your divs become

```
<div class="posthead" ...
```